# SortedSet not adding new constructed objects from certain sql queried results data

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

The answer to the following described issue may be as simple as that I am not using SortedSet correctly, but I wouldn't know if that is the case.

```
void SQLRankGuildsByPoints(final CallbackReturnIntegerStringSortedSet callback)
{
    java.sql.Connection cn = null;
    try {
        cn = DataSource.getConnection();
        if(cn != null)
        {
            PreparedStatement query = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT GuildName, TotalActivityPoints FROM Guilds");

            ResultSet result = query.executeQuery();

            SortedSet<Pair_IntString> GuildsRanking = new TreeSet(new ComparatorGuildsRanking());

            while(result.next())
            {
                int resultInt = result.getInt("TotalActivityPoints");
                String resultString = result.getString("GuildName");

                GuildsRanking.add(new Pair_IntString(resultInt, resultString));
            }

            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(MainClassAccess, new Runnable() { //Callback to main thread
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.onDone(GuildsRanking);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.print(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            cn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.print(e);
        }
    }
}
```

All 8 results from the Guilds table are present in "result" ResultSet.

GuildsRanking.add() isn't adding the new custom Pair_IntString object constructed with the query results, specifically for guilds "test" and "lilo" in Guilds table.

SQLRankGuildsByPoints method finishes it's execution, calling back the GuildsRanking SortedSet without 2 of the iterated results.

This behaviour is unintended and I can't find an explanation for it.

[image: Guilds table]

The comparator used for TreeSet:

```
public class ComparatorGuildsRanking implements Comparator<Pair_IntString> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Pair_IntString intStr1, Pair_IntString intStr2) {
        return intStr2.integer.compareTo(intStr1.integer);
    }
}
```

Custom Pair_IntString class:

```
public class Pair_IntString {
    public Integer integer;
    public String string;

    Pair_IntString(Integer i, String s)
    {
        integer = i;
        string = s;
    }
}
```

No error messages with the skipped add iterations.

Comment: a `Set` does not accept duplicate elements - the `Comparator` is only comparing the `int` values - "test" and "lilo" are not being added because probably "anchoa", with same `int` value (`0`), is already in the `Set`. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html): "*... a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. ...*"

Comment: BTW: 1) you could have used `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.integer` (or, if getter available `Comparator.comparingInt(Pair_IntString::getInteger)` instead of `ComparatorGuildsRanking`; 2) eventual solution: also compare the string if the `integer` value is the same  (e.g. `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> p.integer).thenComparing(p -> p.string)` or similar)

Comment: The proposed solution by @user16320675 works, but the SortedSet gets sorted in the reverse order, as opposed to how it would be read from front to back before, the comparing class I had before circunvented this issue.

But I understand I must compare strings too, maybe I can add that to the class I had before, or maybe I'll need to use something like "NavigableSet" in order to traverse and read the set back to front for displaying ranked entries purposes.

Comment: I just gave the main idea, not a ready to use solution... that must be adjusted as needed. BTW `Comparator` has a method `reversed()`... check its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed())